# Failed filament dryer deformed my filament. Is it salvageable?

Tags: pla, filament, heat-management, recycling

I bought a very famed filament dryer (won't mention the brand) which turned bad on me as I got a failed one; it got exceedingly hot (uneven 60-68 °C) and deformed an almost full PLA spool.

Aside from the spool itself (which was made from recycled PLA), the filament suffered deformation as it contracted and I had to disassemble the whole thing. I haven't checked yet if the diameter suffered a deviation enough to make it nonviable for the printer (it's 1.75 mm), but if not, is it salvageable or should I play it safe?

The PLA itself wasn't also very high quality, I'd like to add, but I don't want the approximately 800g left to go to waste.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on how much the filament is deformed. If there are not many conjoined places, and you can easily unroll the spool, it should be fine. You should also check filament diameter, because if it is too thick, it may clog in some places.

Although, I wouldn't use such filament for important prints. Keep it for prototyping and calibration.